# Noetherian prime ideals and Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $R$ is a commutative ring, and for every $P$ a prime ideal of $R$, $P$ is a Noetherian $R$-module, show that $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: A slightly more challenging exercise would be to show that if every prime ideal of $R$ is finitely generated, then $R$ is a Noetherian ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the statement should be as follows: "Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If every prime ideal of $R$ is noetherian as an $R$-module, then $R$ itself is noetherian."

To prove this, consider an ascending chain of proper ideals $I_0\subseteq I_1\subseteq\cdots\subseteq R.$ Consider the sum $\sum_{i\ge0}I_i,$ which is an ideal $J\subseteq R.$ There are two possibilities:

1. $J=R$
2. $J\subsetneq R$

It should be relatively straightforward to proceed from here, using [Krull's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_theorem) in the second case...

Comment: Maybe simpler: if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then show that $I$ is finitely generated. If $I=R$ is ok. If not, take $P\supset I$ a prime ideal. Since $P$ is a noetherian $R$-module it follows that $I$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @YACP, yes, the choice of formulation will of course depend on the definitions the OP has at hand. It seems to me that either way, we invoke Krull's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look at some proofs of

**[Cohen's theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.3701.pdf)**: A commutative ring $R$ is Noetherian iff all of its prime ideals are finitely generated.

If the prime ideals are Noetherian, then they are obviously finitely generated.